# render data and create nested list item using recursion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, recursion, dom

Here in my code below I want to iterate nested data on initial DOM content load, but the problem is that list is not appended to its parent element. I am passing the parent id as an argument but I am not able to figure out the problem and I am using the recursive approach to iterate the data Please guide me to resolve the problem.

```
const list_wrapper = document.querySelector("#list_wrapper");
let data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "title 1",
        liked: false,
        comment: [{ id: 11, title: "title 1", liked: false, comment: [{ id: 111, title: "title 1", 
liked: false, comment: [{ id: 1111, title: "title 1", liked: false }] }] }],
    },
];
function createCommentListDOM(parEleID, comment) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "list-group-item";
    li.setAttribute("id", comment.id);
    li.innerHTML = `${comment.title}`;
    if (document.getElementById(parEleID) == null) {
        list_wrapper.appendChild(li);
    } else {
        document.getElementById(parEleID).appendChild(li);
    }
}

// Initial DOM render ----------------
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    iterateData(data);
});

function iterateData(arr) {
    arr.map((v) => {
        createCommentListDOM(v.id, v);
        if (v.comment != undefined) {
            return iterateData(v.comment);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this:

- Although it might or might not work, you probably should not call `querySelector` before the *content loaded* callback fires.  You use it to define a global `list_wrapper` variable.  In my rewrite below, we can skip this variable altogether.
- You try to add `<li>` elements as children of `<li>` elements.  They really need a `<ul>` or `<ol>` parent.  We handle this below by creating `<ul>` children of each of our comment `<ul>`s.
- You misuse `map`, which is about transforming lists into other lists.  This is especially noticeable as your `map` callback returns a result on one branch and not another. 
  When what you want is a side-effect such as creating DOM nodes, you should probably use `forEach` instead.  (`map` will still work, but it might confuse readers.)
- You have data that's hard to distinguish, and not really quite enough to show what's going on.  The version below adds a few more nodes, and gives each one a distinct `title`.  This is enough, I think to show the nesting structure without allowing the user to believe that sequential nesting is *all* that's happening.
- Most importantly, your logic has a slight skew.  You pass an object to `createCommentListDOM` to build from, and you pass it as a parentId, *that own object's id*.  This is why the nesting won't work.  There are several ways to fix this.  I chose to pass the parent *node* into `iterateData` and from there into `createCommentListDOM`.  This involves returning the container from `createCommentListDOM`, but that's easy enough.  An alternative would be to pass around the parent ids as you do, but I find this version cleaner.

So here is an alternative version, mostly using your code, but with those changes made:

```js
function createCommentListDOM(parent, comment) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "list-group-item";
    li.innerHTML = `${comment.title}`;
    li.setAttribute("id", comment.id);  // no longer needed?
    const ul = document.createElement("ul"); // need place for children
    li.appendChild(ul);
    parent.appendChild(li);
    return ul;
}

function iterateData(parent, arr) {
    arr.forEach ((v) => {  // not a `map` call
        const newParent = createCommentListDOM(parent, v);
        if (v.comment != undefined) {
            iterateData(newParent, v.comment);  // no `return` here
        }
    });
}

let data = [
  { id: 1, title: "title 1",  liked: false, comment: [
    { id: 11, title: "title 11", liked: false, comment: [
      { id: 111, title: "title 111", liked: false, comment: [
        { id: 1111, title: "title 1111", liked: false }
      ]},
      { id: 112, title: "title 112", liked: false},
      { id: 113, title: "title 113", liked: false}
    ]}
  ]}, 
  { id: 2, title: "title 2", liked: false, comment: [
    { id: 21, title: "title 21", liked: false }
  ]}
];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // should probably not call querySelector before content loaded
  iterateData(document.querySelector("#list_wrapper"), data); 
});
```

```html
<ul id="list_wrapper"></ul>
```